# Android saxparser CDATA ignorance

Tags: java, android, sax, saxparser

I have a XML file where I have a tag called `TEXT`

When I am trying to parse the file with android's `org.xml.sax` parser, the whole tag is not being parsed , first few characters are only parsed

Here is my `TEXT` tag

```
<TEXT><![CDATA[<p><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: medium;">Sample text&rdquo;</span></p>
<p><span style="font-size: medium;"><img style="float: left;" title="Posted by : 5_1.jpg" src="http://www.gg.com/5_1.jpg" alt="" width="60" height="178" />&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size: medium;">sample text</span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><span style="font-size: small;"><strong><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Situation,</span></strong></span></p>
<p><span style="font-size: small;"><strong><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Problem,</span></strong></span></p>
<p><span style="font-size: small;"><strong><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Implication,</span></strong></span></p>
<p><span style="font-size: small;"><strong><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Need-payoff</span></strong></span></p>]]></TEXT>
```

Now when I parese the tag I am only getting the `sample data` which ends with `</p>`

Altough me tag is embaded with a `CDATA` tag so what is the reason for the problem and how can I find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely your parsing code is assuming that the parser will return the entire text node all at once. SAX parsers are allowed to divide a text node into chunks and return each chunk separately.

Comment: Then how can I achieve me goal..?